# robot_state_publisher with SDF Files

Tags: ros, sdf, robot-state-publisher, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just want to ask about the support of robot_state_publisher with SDF Files, can we use it to broadcast the state of the robot to the TF Transform Library using SDF Files (not URDF Files).

One related link: http://answers.ros.org/question/61097/using-robot_state_publisher-with-a-sdf-file/ but it is couple of years old and I was wondering whether there has been any change.

Thanks.
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204803/robot_state_publisher-with-sdf-files/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-03-13**:
Im really interested in this as well, as i would like to visualize the robot in rviz, but my gazebo model requires closed loop joints, so i need to use a SDF description for gazebo. I dont think your can pass both a URDF and SDF into the robot_description parameter.. not sure if im correct though.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-03-13**:
The issue is with robot_state_publisher to convert Joint States to TF Transforms which is only compatible with URDF files. There is no direct way to do this using SDF files. One option can be to add SDF support to get the TF transforms which can be challenging OR just maintain 2 copies(SDF and URDF)

**Comment by [owais2k12](https://answers.ros.org/users/28041/owais2k12/) on 2017-11-08**:
I am facing the similar issue, has anyone solved this problem. If yes, kindly share the details. If not, can you explain a little bit how we can make use of URDF and SDF at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an open ticket against gazebo to create a SDF to URDF conversion tool: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1482/sdf-to-urdf-convertor

Since the URDF is used in several places in ROS, it makes sense to try to convert an SDF into a URDF so that it can be visualized by rviz and used with robot_state_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4